# How can I emulate GPIO button presses over SSH connection?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am working with the raspberry pi, and I have an application on the other end that is supposed to respond to button presses. The problem that I have is that I am not in the room of the Pi that is running and therefore I have no way to push the button. Is there a way that I can somehow emulate a button press via a ssh terminal that way my python program will pick up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run a Web server on your PI . Call (http) a script (php) from remote machine.  And the script will do the work locally.

Comment: I need a way to emulate the button press for testing purposes.. Like the physical button in the room.